# Creating a new 200 OK page on an address that previously served a 301 redirect?

Tags: seo, redirects, url, 301-redirect

Let's say I create a page `aaa.htm`; after some time it gets removed in favor of `bbb.htm`.

At this point `aaa.htm` responds with a 301 redirect to `bbb.htm`.

Now again, after some more amount of time, I create a new `aaa.htm` file again that now responds with status 200.

Is this practice bad?

Comment: What do you intend to do with bbb? 301 it back to aaa? since this could cause problems.

Comment: no i mean two different pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't view 301 redirects as completely permanent.  It re-crawls them periodically to check for cases like this.

If you publish a new page on a URL that used to redirect, Google will eventually find it and index it.  The only drawback may be that they would find it faster on a fresh URL.